# Свойство layout_gravity в коде

Tags: java, android

Как задать свойство layout_gravity для TextView в коде?

Comment: а какой у вас layout?

Comment: У меня LinearLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

button.setLayoutParams(params);
```